# React Native + Expo + Axios, why need to use 10.0.2.2 instead locahost?

Tags: react-native, rest, axios, expo, json-server

I was working on a React Native app using Axios to make API requests until before making this change to 10.0.2.2, I kept getting a direct Axios Network Error. Why doesn't it work to use localhost?

I fixed that problem ok?